# is it possible to do a mongodb request but return 5 row with your item in the middle?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how can i performe a mongodb reques on users document with a username filter (the user name is unique), but i want a result of 5 users, 2 befor and 2 after the user (the users are sorted for example by a score).

Comment: please share what you tried

Comment: I don’t know how to star because i don’t know if it’s possible.
For the collection it’s juste thousands, and kbytes for documents.

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from MongoDB 5.0**, you can use [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#definition) to achieve the behaviour your want.

Assuming you have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "rank": 2
}
```

And you want to find "near" 5 documents of "name5", ordering by the field `rank`. For a test case I used(which is a repetition of the sample doc by ranging the id from 1 to 10 like below:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "rank": 2
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "rank": 4
},
...
{
    "_id": 10,
    "name": "name10",
    "rank": 20
}
```

I deliberately choosing the `rank` to be ranged from 2:20:2 to demonstrate the sorting feasibility.

By using the `$setWindowFiels` like below, you can get `_id` of the "near 5" documents:

```
{
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "rank": 1
      },
      "output": {
        nearIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id",
          window: {
            documents: [
              -2,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Explanation:

1. `partitionBy: null` : no specific partition/grouping for your case
2. `"sortBy": {"rank": 1}` : define `rank` as the ordering of "near"
3. `"output": {nearIds: {$addToSet: "$_id",...` : the output will be stored in an array named `nearIds`
4. `window: {documents: [-2, 2]}`: to find in the range of -2 documents i.e. previous 2 and 2 documents i.e. next 2 documents

The output `nearIds` will be like this:

```
...
{
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "nearIds": [
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ],
    "rank": 8
},
{
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "name5",
    "nearIds": [
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7
    ],
    "rank": 10
}
...
```

You can see "near 5" ids are grouped into array. You can then used the ids in `nearIds` to `$lookup` and `$replaceRoot` to wrangle to your desired format of output.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xPo22wt5jdm) for your reference.