# Find 2 documents within distance to each other in sorted collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My goal is to find two random documents. Each document has a rating. The rating difference between these two document doesn't matter to me. But what matters is the "distance in documents" between these two documents.

Take this list for example. Say the aggregation randomly selects `Person7`. Now I want a random document say max 3 documents away from `Person7`. So in this case it should be either `Person4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10`.

```json
    [
     { name: "Person1", rating: 50 },
     { name: "Person2", rating: 55 },
     { name: "Person3", rating: 60 },
     { name: "Person4", rating: 65 },
     { name: "Person5", rating: 70 },
     { name: "Person6", rating: 75 },
     { name: "Person7", rating: 800 },
     { name: "Person8", rating: 850 },
     { name: "Person9", rating: 900 },
     { name: "Person10", rating: 100000 },
     { name: "Person11", rating: 100001 },
     { name: "Person12", rating: 102000 }
    ]
```

And in the end I would like to end up with both of these randomly selected documentes as a result of the pipeline. So for example "Person2" and "Person5" or "Person8" and "Person11", but not "Person1" and "Person5" since the distance between them is beyond 3.

I think I would have to aggregate this list but I'm not sure what type of aggregations to run. Also I'm not sure one aggregation is enough. I would maybe need to two this in multiple steps(in a transaction).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to do a mongodb request but return 5 row with your item in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69610464/14732669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB v5.0+, you can use [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#definition) to get the nearby documents. You can then use `$sample` to randomly get a one document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "rating": 1
      },
      "output": {
        nearDocs: {
          $addToSet: "$_id",
          window: {
            documents: [
              -3,
              3
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "nearDocs",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "nearDocs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$nearDocs"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$_id",
          "$nearDocs._id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      matchPairs: [
        {
          _id: "_id",
          name: "$name",
          rating: "$rating"
        },
        "$nearDocs"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$matchPairs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$matchPairs"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kXeFr8qcrtN) for your reference.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so instead of hardcoding "Person7" in there it would randomize that document as well? I was hoping this could be done in a single aggregation.

Comment: @hornta updated to use `$sample` to randomly choose document

Comment: Cool, a lot of new operators to learn I see. I hate to be a one that just asks for me and I think in time I could figure it out but what if I would want to get the first randomized document out as well? Would it have to be sent down the pipeline and be concatenated with the last sample?

Comment: What do you mean by *first randomized document*? The current version already doing 2 `$sample`  to randomly select document. The 1st one pick a random document. The 2nd one pick one nearby document.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get these 2 documents out from the aggregation, I should maybe have clarified it in the top question :) I updated the question.

Comment: @hornta the 2nd random selection is bounded within your defined range. Isn't that sufficing your requirement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245190/discussion-between-hornta-and-ray).